# How to implement a "dynamic_cast"-like operator between shared_ptr's?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

Consider a `class D` derived from a `class B`, and a `sb` instance of `std::shared_ptr<B>`. Once I have verified that `dynamic_cast<D*>(sb.get())` is possible, I want to create a proper `std::shared_ptr<D>` from sb. In other words, I'd like to implement a kind of `dynami_cast<>` between shared_ptr's. How can I do this in a clean way? A possible solution would be to make B derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and to use `shared_from_this()` from the (casted) pointer to `D`. But this would require a change in the definition of type B. Are there better ideas? Is there anything in `boost`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you aware of `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Answer (score 3):

As other answers pointed out, the standard library already provides what you want, but for completeness, implementing it is easy:

```
template<typename To, typename From>
  std::shared_ptr<To>
  dynamic_pointer_cast(const std::shared_ptr<From>& from)
  {
    return std::shared_ptr<To>(from, dynamic_cast<To*>(from.get()));
  }
```

This uses the aliasing constructor to create a new `shared_ptr` of a different type that shares ownership with `from`, so they share the same reference count even though they own different pointers (in this case the pointers they own are different types but point to the same object, but that doesn't have to be true.)

This isn't quite right, because if the cast fails (returning a null pointer) you get a `shared_ptr` that stores a null pointer, but shares ownership with a non-null pointer. To handle that we need a small tweak:

```
template<typename To, typename From>
  std::shared_ptr<To>
  dynamic_pointer_cast(const std::shared_ptr<From>& from)
  {
    if (auto p = dynamic_cast<To*>(from.get()))
      return std::shared_ptr<To>(from, p);
    return {};
  }
```

Now we return an empty `shared_ptr<To>` if the cast fails, which is a better match to the behaviour of `dynamic_cast<To*>`.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [dynamic_pointer_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)